# If infinity were a number, would it then be true to have 1/infinity equal to 0?

Tags: limits, infinity

Lately I have been having a discussion on infinity. Personally I do not see this as a number, but as a concept. The person I was speaking with, asked me to assume for the time being that $\infty$ is a number, however. Let us assume this for this question.

As we know, we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$. I can understand this, as it is visible in a plot of the function $\frac{1}{x}$ that $x$ approaches zero if $x$ becomes very large.
However, now that we assume that $\infty$ is a number, can we conclude that $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$? 
My friend thinks this makes sense, but I cannot wrap around this. Maybe my thinking is not developed enough to actually think of $\infty$ as a number.

Also, I am aware that there are different sizes of infinity, put simply. Does it matter for this question which one you think about?

Comment: What is a number?

Comment: The answer is yes. You're referring to the *extended* real number line. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: What then to make of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?

Comment: @Paul Read the Wikipedia article cited by Adam

Comment: You also have this on subject https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number

Comment: Be very careful about what you thought you know about how arithmetic works if you start to include infinity.  For example, while it may be true that $\dfrac{1}{x}\times x = 1$ for all finite non-zero $x$... this does not need to be true for when $x=\infty$ or when $x=0$.  Equivalently, $0\times x = 0$ for all finite $x$ but what happens when $x=\infty$?  There will be several expressions that are left undefined and several conveniences of our original number system that we lose when extending to include $\infty$, the cost of which is often too much to justify in normal circumstances.

Comment: Treating $\infty$ as a number leads to all sort of contradictions , as also pointed out in the below answer. And all those stuff as "extended real line" or "hyperreal number" or whatsoever does not make $\infty$ a number ! Those concepts are completely different. Expressions like $\frac{1}{\infty}$ are only meaningful in the context of limits , we cannot just "plug in $\infty$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the *consequences* of the hypothetical

> assume for the time being that ∞ is a number

Assuming "$\infty$ is a number" is implicitly assuming that it along with the ordinary numbers follows the usual rules of arithmetic.  Then you find many contradictions. Once it's a number you have to allow $\infty + 1$. If that turns out to be $\infty$ then $1=0$. If it turns out to be some ordinary number then subtraction tells you $\infty$ is an ordinary number too.

There are many places in mathematics where it's convenient to use the symbol $\infty$. None of those treats it as a number.